# Node.js app in Heroku crashes when I close the cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, cmd

I'm running a node.js app using Heroku.

From my git repository folder, I'm doing: `heroku run node main.js`.

It all works fine, the app starts running. But when I close the command prompt window, the app stops working. Shouldn't it keep running in Heroku's servers?

Comment: Not familiar with `heroku run` but the typical workflow is to push your git repository to heroku's `master` branch and make sure your `package.json` has a `main` entry containing a command to start the server process.

Comment: checkout this https://appdividend.com/2018/04/14/how-to-deploy-nodejs-app-to-heroku/#Step_4_CreateProcfile

Comment: @RamiJarrar not sure why you didn't just link to [heroku's own article...](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#deploy-your-application-to-heroku)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `heroku run` command launches a [One-Off Dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#formation-dynos-vs-one-off-dynos), which is basically a dyno attached to your terminal and therefore it closes when you close the terminal.

In your case, you may want to check the Heroku's guide on [Deploying Node.js Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs)